# Using image as border- CSS3- browser compatible

Tags: css

Recently i have come up with problem with background image like a ipad theme that contain a video, problem is that size of video may change, so i thought of trying border- image properties of CSS3. the major properties of css3 could be made cross browser compatible by using some technique or other. currently i use css PIE. but it doesn't support image border property in its recent version, IS there any way round. Just need to fix it. IE is really a pain :(

I thought of using some "Ninja in your browser" script it didn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. There's currently no way to get border-image into all versions of Internet Explorer. PIE is working on it for IE9, from what I've found, but ran into some breaking problems ([see more info in this duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828795/how-can-i-get-css3-border-image-working-in-ie9/5845576#5845576)).

From the sound of it, your best bet is probably to allow IE to gracefully degrade by using a simple border or background.