# How can I get css3 border-image working in IE9?

Tags: internet-explorer-9, css

I'm using border-image which works in all browsers except IE. For IE versions 7 and 8, I have css3pie which makes it work. But I haven't been able to find any plugin to make it work in IE9. Is there a way I can hack it so it works in IE9 as well?

Answer (score 1):

I found some static about PIE attempting to add it, but having some issue. They might be able to get it in the near future, though.

Until then, you have two options:

1. Allow IE to degrade gracefully. This is not a bad thing, as designs don't have to look the same in all browsers. However, since you already have IE8 and below working, it might be counterproductive to degrade in a newer browser (though, theoretically, you could just nix all IE for the time being). This also depends on what your border image looks like (you might be able to get away with a subtle border, such as a two-toned one, but not a more intricate one).
2. Use a workaround, such as [this hackish one](http://blog.rafaljonca.org/2011/01/ie9-and-fancy-border-image-buttons.html), or possibly [the .htc file in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567501/border-image-workaround-for-ie) (or even the hackish workaround answer).